# CQRS - Passing complex paging / filtering data through the domain

Tags: c#, cqrs, devextreme

I am trying to implement the cqrs pattern using mediatr and all is set up correctly and working well. I do however have an issue when trying to implement the devextreme components in my views. The components require an endpoint that accepts a DataSourceLoadOptions object which can then be coupled with the DataSourceLoader class and an IQueryable object to automate filtering/paging/sorting etc. This code is fantastic and really gets rid of a lot of boilerplate stuff.

Here is an example of the "old way" I used to do things :

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual object Get(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
{
    var queryable = this.context.Set<TEntity>();

    return DataSourceLoader.Load(queryable, loadOptions);
}
```

As you can see it is really is quite nice, however it is old school and not layered and couples me to EF as a persistence mechanism. But now to replace this with a CQRS pattern is going to be a bit tricky because I do not want my application or domain or even database layer to know about devextreme ( its a view technology and must remain there ). I also am not really keen on returning a simple IQueryable from the mediatr response as that means things like keeping the context alive / testability issues / some Linq queries cannot be materialized int SQL etc...smells bad.

I am wondering if there is another way to somehow extract out an interface and then maybe create a service that I can inject through DI to resolve this? I cant really find any resources on the net regarding this. As per usual all the example are just "hello world" use cases and none of them really get their hands dirty with "real world" problems like filtering / paging / Identity etc

If anyone has any ideas, please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are using Kendo UI, but the problem is the same. We are returning `IQueryable<T>` from our queries for cases where we need paging done for the UI. And then we have a test that ensures that the query can be executed with pure SQL.

Something like this:

```
public class MyProjectQuery : IQuery<IEnumerable<Project>
{
// params
}

[HttpGet]
public virtual object Get(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
{
    var queryable = _mediator.Query(new MyProjectQuery());

    return DataSourceLoader.Load(queryable, loadOptions);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @trailmax, I'm going to mark your answer as correct as I have already implemented it as such and cant wait any longer for alternative suggestions